# Expression Engine + FreeForms Pro --> MS Dynamics Integration

Tags: solspace-freeform, php, database-migrations, integration

At the moment we have a website running on Expression Engine with FreeForms Pro. We hope to integrate the forms in a way that this data exists in our MS Dynamics CRM package.

What's the best way to realize this? Would there be any example code/demos online or would this be something only specific vendors could do?

Hope to hear from you.

Many thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to this:

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3295c3c-a446-471d-9f30-1753a3e591d0/ms-dynamics-crm-api?forum=crm

MS Dynamics CRM supports a web-surface API in the SDK. And according to me, you can develop your own extensions and modules using the FreeForm extension hooks and the ExpressionEngine addon developers guides:

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/extension_hooks/

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/

Soooo unless you can expand on your answer, a good developer (especially one familiar with EE addon development) should have no problem solving this for you. As for code examples, use the SDK guide to learn about the Dynamics CRM API, and use the EE addon guides to learn about how to connect your server to that API, and use the FreeForm extension hooks to grab data submitted by FreeForm in your custom modules and extensions (that then connect to the CRM API).

Answer (score 0):

Peter,

As jrothafer pointed out, you can reference the documentation for each platform (including the Freeform extension hooks) and build a solution that will do what you want. I don't know of any one tutuorial that covers this specific case. Of course, that's the trouble with API integrations: they tend to be specific to the project.

There are a lot of development companies out there that can do the customization work for you. Solspace, who makes Freeform, also does custom CRM integrations (see: https://solspace.com/services/salesforce) and might be able to help.